# log4j2 filePattern doesn't interpolate

Tags: log4j2, rollingfileappender

I've tried to add the following RollingFile appender;

```
    <RollingFile name="appFile" fileName="${sys:catalina.base}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}${web:contextPath}${sys:file.separator}app.log" filePattern="app-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c{2} - %m%n" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
    </RollingFile>
```

The file is created in the correct path but the name is always the same (app.log) instead of app-xx-xx-xxxx.log.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `filePattern` attribute is the *pattern* of the file name to use on **rollover**. But if you want the date pattern in the name of the file that is actively written tom, you can use [Date Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#DateLookup) in the `filename` attribute, i.e:

```
fileName="${sys:catalina.base}${sys:file.separator}logs${sys:file.separator}${web:contextPath}${sys:file.separator}app-${date:dd-MM-yyyy}.log"
```

Comment: Just as an addendum - if you are just using a fire once log file, you need to change RollingFile to just File.  That said - thank you - has taken me over an hour to find this simple answer - apparently google doesn't consider "not working" the same as "doesn't work".